# Testing monthly in-app subscription

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, subscription

I'm using the v3 api for in-app billing in my app and I'm using a subscription. In the developer console I set the subscription with a monthly period and 30 days of trial. I published my app as beta and I added one of my account as tester in the developer console settings page. Now when I click on the buy button, the play store shows me all the information BUT it tell me that the charge is every day and with only 1 day of trial. Is it the default when testing or am I missing something?

Comment: Hello @greywolf82,I hope you have solved this problem.Can you please look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756889/unable-to-test-in-app-subscription

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every TEST subscription has an active period of 1 day, regardless of what the real subscription's active and trial periods are. They will be renewed every 24 hours but they will never be charged.

In order to test a real subscription, you'd have to remove your account from the "Gmail accounts with testing access" field in the Developer Console's settings or use a different account. Then it should work as expected (30 day trial + monthly renewal), but the amount WILL be charged to your account once the trial period ends.

But if the test subscription works, there should be no reason for a real subscription to fail. I think.