# Android - In App Purchases - Purchasing with a test account is limited to one a day

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I've implemented IAB in my app as described in [Preparing Your In-app Billing Application](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html). I have 2 subscriptions defined in the store and i added my gmail account to "Gmail accounts with testing access".

When i perform a subscription purchase via `mHelper.launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow()` i noticed that im limited to one purchase per day per subscription. After each purchase im going to the store and canceling the subscription but when i try to purchase again im getting `-1008 error - IAB returned null purchaseData or dataSignature`.

any idea whats wrong here ? Is this a new policy by google ?

Comment: This should not happen.If you cancel subscription then you can buy it again in testing mode.

Comment: @kgandroid its happening. I should mention that up until recently everything worked just fine with sandbox purchasing. Which makes me think that its something on google side.

Comment: You are using Inapp purchase V3 right??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756889/unable-to-test-in-app-subscription I have implemented in app subscription in one of my project and it is up and running successfully in play store.But as far as I remember I didnt came across any method like: launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow()

Comment: @kgandroid its in the official sample app - https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/IabHelper.java. its the same as launchPurchaseFlow() but with "subs" as itemType.

Comment: did you try test purchase your subscriptions recently ?

Comment: yEs...I didnt follow this way of coding or methods.